# How to pull from private repo in a bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket pipeline that works well but now on a project I need to pull from a private repository which contains a package that is required in my composer.json.

When I do a `composer install` in the pipeline, it stops with this error

```
Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout 'git@bitbucket.org:company/package.git' [...]
  Cloning into '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/company/package'...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  Permission denied (publickey).                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  Please make sure you have the correct access rights                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  and the repository exists.
```

The pipeline do not have any SSH key defined so it's not allowed to pull, but how could I define one since it's ephemeral?

Or maybe I should define the requirement otherwise?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Add a deployment key (public SSH key) to the private repository
- Add that key’s corresponding private key (Base64-encoded) as environment variable in the repo that has the Pipeline. Ideally, this should be marked as protected, which will hide it.
- Use the environment variable (Base64-decoded) in the Pipeline. Ususally, that means something like writing it to the user’s `.ssh` directory.

That should be enough to get it running.

Moreover, I’ve just seen that there is now (maybe this is new, but I’m not sure) a new page “Settings” > “Pipelines” > “SSH keys” for managing pipelines SSH keys. This way, you wouldn’t even need to add the private key to the docker image you are using. But I haven’t used that so far, so I can’t say anything about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was about to post this tuto that gives the same information :) https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-do-I-set-up-ssh-public-key-authentication-so-that-I-can-use/qaq-p/171671